# Extend year range in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

By default, odoo (openerp 8.0) fields.date combobox only show year selection in range of +/-10 years from current year. How could we extend it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow this way I just try to do something like this from my end

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp import tools
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime

class myclass_nextyear(osv.Model):
    _name='myclass.nextyear'

    def str_to_datetime(strdate):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(strdate, tools.DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT)


    def compute_next_year_date(self, strdate):
        oneyear = datetime.timedelta(days=365)
        curdate = str_to_datetime(strdate)
        return datetime.datetime.strftime(curdate + oneyear, tools.DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT)

    _columns = {
         'start_date': fields.date('Contract Start Date', help='Date when the coverage of the contract begins'),
         'expiration_date': fields.date('Contract Expiration Date', help='Date when the coverage of the contract expirates (by default, one year after begin date)'),
      }

    _defaults = {
        'start_date': fields.date.context_today,
        'expiration_date': lambda self, cr, uid, ctx: self.compute_next_year_date(fields.date.context_today(self, cr, uid, context=ctx)),
        }
```

Above the **start date** comes as the current date as default and the **expiration date** comes as the function field as from 
**compute_next_year_date** function

I hope this should helpful for you ..! :)

Answer (score 2):

The ultimate source is in the `odoo/odoo/addons/web/static/lib/jquery.ui/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js` which sets the year Range to be `c-10:c+10`, i.e. current - 10 years to current + 10 years. 
 \That's why you are seeing years from 2005 to 2025 this year.  The DatePicker instance, I think, its instantiated in the `odoo/odoo/addons/web/static/src/js/view_form.js` file (search for the start method of instance.web.DateTimeWidget).  You can either change it from that file (add `yearRange` in `setDefaults` to your satisfaction) or override the start method of instance.web.DateTimeWidget

Comment: "or override the start method of instance.web.DateTimeWidget" sounds interesting. Any hints on how to do that?

Comment: This can solve the problem easily but if i need more than one yearRange for different date picker there may be some trouble.